# Using Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient) with Game Services

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, google-play-games, google-api-java-client

I'm using `Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient)` to prompt the user to select their account for a game I'm creating using Cordova. I have built the Google API Client in this manner:

```
GoogleSignInOptions.Builder gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN);

GoogleApiClient.Builder builder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(webView.getContext())
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .addApi(Games.API)
    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso.build());

mGoogleApiClient = builder.build();

private void signIn() {
    if (!this.mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(this.mGoogleApiClient);
        cordova.getActivity().startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
    return;
}
```

The problem is `Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient)` isn't producing a popup that allows the user to select an account; but rather, automatically selects one of the emails and displays something like the following: [image]

Comment: Have you tried the third option from [Games authentication adopting Google Sign-In API](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/games-authentication-adopting-google.html), GoogleSignInOptions gso = new
     GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
         .requestEmail()
         .build(); ?

Comment: I discovered that clicking "DENY" takes the user back to the screen which allows them to select an account. Once the user selects an account, they are directed back to the "ALLOW/DENY" screen [above]. I believe the first option should be the account selection view.

Comment: ok, so you've got it working?

Comment: Not really. If a user has more than one account, they should be allowed to select an account before seeing the above screen.

Comment: what happens if you try the 3rd option I mentioned, same results?

Comment: All that does is display an additional message to the user that states the application would like to "View your email address".